When deleting my circular linked list class, the L variable turns into random addresses
I'm making a circular linked list class in C++, everything works as expected, except for when i delete an object made based on my class. In the destructor, i'm deleting every single element plus the L itself at the end, and setting it to nullptr so when the user tries to use the object's functions again, the if (L == nullptr) return; will stop them.
the problem is, the L = nullptr actually works fine but when i use another function like printArray() or any other one like get()(which haven't included in the code) it actually shows that L is equal to 4 very random memory addresses and the last one somehow points back to L itself! (this is actually the situation when i delete the L, but when i set it to nullptr it will be 0x0 meaning it doesn't point to those random addresses).
#include <iostream>
class list
{
    private:
        unsigned int size;
        struct node {
            int item;
            node *next = nullptr;
        };
        node *L;
        bool deleted;
    public:
        list() {
            size = 0;
            L = new node;
            L->next = L;
            deleted = false;
        }
        ~list() {
            if (L != nullptr) {
                popAll();
                std::cout << L->next << std::endl;
                delete L;
                std::cout << L->next << std::endl;
                L = nullptr;
                deleted = true;
            }
        }
        void printArray() {
            if (deleted && L == nullptr) return;
            node *p = L->next;
            std::cout << '[';
            while (p != L) {
                std::cout << p->item;
                if (p->next != L) std::cout << ", ";
                p = p->next;
            }
            std::cout << ']';
        }
        void popAll() {
            if (deleted && L == nullptr) return;
            node *p = L->next;
            while (p != L) {
                node *n = p->next;
                delete p;
                p = n;
            }
            L->next = L;
            size = 0;
        }
};

I also have the deleted boolean but that's just as a fallback for me if this fails again. Because if i use the deleted as a detector for when the object is deleted, it'll work fine but i wanna know why the L is a nullptr after i set it to it in the destructor, but it doesn't change it in the other functions and it's like it's only been deleted and not even set to nullptr.

Once you have passed a pointer to delete, you can never dereference that pointer again until you make it point somewhere else valid. If you attempt to dereference the pointer (which you do in the list destructor) then you will have undefined behavior.

On a couple of different notes, it's okay to delete a null pointer; And you don't delete all nodes in the list in the list destructor, only the first one. You also don't need to make the pointer a null pointer in the destructor, as the member variables should never be used again. The whole deleted flag and L == nullptr checks seems to be covering for some other bug in your code.

More generically about lists, I recommend you keep track of its size using a separate variable. And also have a pointer to the last node, which will be making it much easier to append nodes to the end of the list, or retrieve the last node from the list. And always use pencil and paper to help you visualize the lists. Like for example when you debug the code, draw the list and the nodes and the pointers, to see what really happens with them.

never #include a file inside a class, I'm surprised your code even compiles. Please show a [mre]

Hey thx dude! the first comment made me understand this a bit more since i'm just learning the C++. For the second one, in the popAll() i am actually deleting every single element, but something to take note of... i'm actually using L as just an empty slot so it has no item in it and it's just to point to the first element in the list. The idea of setting L to null was came from AI because it seems like in C++ u can still use an object's functions once it's deleted, so setting it to null will let me check if it's deleted if someone tried to use the functions again. Have u tried my code?

Yeah i didn't expect it to work either but it did for some reason, i'll bring it out of there now. And yeah sorry i totally forgot about that minimal reproducible rule.

also @Someprogrammerdude, i know i could like make to point to next and previous or just have pointers for the first and the last elements but our teacher says i should try every single one, make different classes for each and present it to our class.

"The idea of setting L to null was came from AI because it seems like in C++ u can still use an object's functions once it's deleted," The AI is hallucinating if it's telling you that you can use an object after it has been deleted.

One big Undefined Behavior: delete L; std::cout << L->next << std::endl; You can't use pointer after it object it point to was deleted! https://godbolt.org/z/58T3hrnEx Also where is implementation of popAll();?

@PeteKirkham yeah it was surprising for me too

@MarekR Oh sorry i had to delete those ones, lol! but one fact: they still work even if L is deleted. Also the popAll() works fine and doesn't do anything weird to L so i didn't put it there to make the code minimal, maybe i'll do it now.

Please provide MCVE https://godbolt.org/z/qoe4nfEGv

"lol! but one fact: they still work even if L is deleted.": that is just a matter of chance. Accessing freed memory leads to undefined behaviour, including behaviour that you may like. It is a source of problems. But: (1) Executing L = nullptr and deleted = true is useless when that memory is about to be released, so (2) testing for deleted  to be true or L == nullptr is useless, as it should never happen (3) You access a deleted list (in code you have not shared) which is the source of the problems. You should never do that.

@trincot Firstly, i actually solved the problem a minute ago, using the same method but i put the structure declearation and the L's definition on top of the class instead of the class's private section. But, i still kinda wanna know why when i changed L in the destructor, it didn;t change it in the private section, so right now i'm kinda focusing on this one or if u think there's nothing else i can do then i'll just go ahead and answer the question.

@trincot Secondly, I mean i deleted L and expected user to not to use the object again, but even if they will, i want them to fail. So i had to put some if statements to make that happen and changed L to be nullptr so it'll be fully empty pointing at nothing, which it did happen but not like... globally... u know? So it's obviously a scope kind of problem, which i wanna know why, or if there's any other way to do the same with the deleted object so it won't be usable then i'd like to know it. From what u mentioned, i'm actually freeing L setting it to nullptr in it if u got it wrong.

@trincot or i just... didn't get what u mean by that comment. But as i said, i've solved it already i just wanna know why it didn't change it while it was in the private section and can i make the structure and the L to be private and only usable within the .hpp itself or not.

"expected user to not to use the object again, but even if they will, i want them to fail.": you cannot assure that. If the "user" uses a pointer to freed memory they will get indefined behaviour. There is really nothing more to it, and nothing that you can alter to make defined behaviour. The main point is that it is just bad code when that code accesses deallocated memory.  You should not attempt to try to fix the undefined behaviour that is caused by the user's bad code: it's their responsibility to fix bad code.

"changed L to be nullptr": which is futile. That memory is freed once the destructor finishes, and you have no control over what that memory is being used for after that. There is absolutely no guarantee that any faulty code that accesses that memory will read a nullptr at that spot. It is really useless to try to leave something there.

"So it's obviously a scope kind of problem": no it is not. It is undefined bahaviour, which means anything can happen, and that includes that it does what you expect -- but that is just matter of luck, and may turn out differently the next time.

"i've solved it already": I don't think you did.

"i just wanna know why it didn't change it while it was in the private section": that's just  luck. It can turn out differently too. That's what undefined behaviour means. Don't try to find a pattern in it (when does it work, when does it not work). Instead, embrace the fact that accessing freed memory in some "user" code is either your responsibility, and then you should fix that part of the code, or it is someone else's code, and then it is up to them to fix it.

@trincot Alright then, so u mean what i did might just not work in another project? since there might be something else in the memory of L since it's freed? and it was really just luck that it didn't change L back in the destructor?(cause i actually tried not deleting it and instead just setting it to a nullptr but that didn't work either) or wait,,, r u just saying that even if i set L to nullptr.. since the memory is freed, there's no telling if L will be a nullptr after a few milliseconds since the memory will keep changing? if so... then what exactly can be the solution?!

Please read all my comments. Undefined behavior is caused by accessing freed memory. The fix is that no such access should be made. Full stop.

@trincot i mean the whole point was just not to let the user use the object again, which then u said we can't stop them, popAll() already does the trick for deleting every single element, destructor also calls popAll() in addition to deleting the L itself so... ur trying to tell me the only way i can make users not to use it after deleting the object is to just create a boolean for it? (i think i clearly understood what u meant about undefined behavior thx to ur explainations)

@trincot Ok, think i got it.

bool deleted is utterly unnecessary. It's like writing "poured out" on water that is to be poured out. Once you destroy the object, it is gone forever. You cannot check if the object is gone by looking at the object itself. If it's gone, you have nothing to look at.

Also, list(list const&) = delete; and void operator=(list const&) = delete;.  Because otherwise you'll have two objects managing the same memory.  And that's bad.

@Eljay great point but... can u show me a sample? i don't exactly understand where to put these two.. maybe just because i'm a beginner to C++

Put them just after public:.

Got it! can't thank u guys enough for all ur help!


...setting it to nullptr so when the user tries to use the object's functions again, the if (L == nullptr) return; will stop them.

The word "user" is referring here to some code with bugs. It is a bug to access a deleted object (the list instance). We imagine a scenario like this for the "user" code:
list *mylist = new list;
// ... some more code
// ... and when done:
delete mylist;
// ...but then they still make an access:
mylist->printArray();

That last statement is a bug. It leads to undefined behaviour. The user code is bad, it must be fixed. The memory that mylist points to has been freed and might have unrelated content. There is nothing in that memory you can leave behind as a protection, since you told the system that it is free, and that means the system can do with (and write to) it whatever else it can use it for.

the L = nullptr actually works fine

That statement in the destructor is unnecessary, and doesn't help. No other code can reliably read that nullptr value after the destructor has completed and the memory has been freed.

but when i use another function like printArray() or any other one like get() (which haven't included in the code) it actually shows that L is equal to 4 very random memory addresses

That is not unusual. After the destructor has run, any code that tries to access a method or field of the deleted object represents a bug. That memory that previously held L, is no longer under your code's control, and could be anything. It should not be accessed. Any code that does access it, has a bug.

I also have the deleted boolean

That doesn't help. Your destructor sets deleted to true, but that is useless, because the very next moment, when the memory of the list has been freed, that deleted resides in freed memory, so the value at that location could be anything, as it could already be in use for something else. It should not be accessed by your (or user's) code, nor is it reliable.

if i use the deleted as a detector for when the object is deleted, it'll work fine

That is just a matter of chance. Accessing the deleted field of a deleted list instance leads to undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour may mean it does something else, crashes the program, or... does what you expect. It can be determined by factors that are not under the program's control.

but i wanna know why the L is a nullptr after i set it to it in the destructor, but it doesn't change it in the other functions and it's like it's only been deleted and not even set to nullptr.

The memory occupied by L has been freed. It can be used for other purposes. It should not be accessed. Any code that does attempt to access it, represents a bug.
What to do
Don't worry about bugs in code that is not under your control. If someone writes "user" code that accesses a list instance after they have deleted it, they have introduced a bug in their program. That is their responsibility. You should not try to fix that situation in your class, nor can you. It is the responsibility of the coder to never write code that accesses memory that has been freed.
Your destructor should not set any instance fields to some other values in the hope that it will serve a purpose after the destructor has finished, as that is useless.
Instead just do the following in your destructor, and let all coders using your code take their responsibility to write code that does not access freed memory:
        ~list() {
            // It is guaranteed that `L` is not `nullptr`, as there is no code
            //    anymore that sets it to that value.
            popAll(); // Free all data nodes
            delete L; // Delete the "sentinel" node allocated in the constructor
        }

Remove all those initial if statements that try to detect that it is running on a deleted object. That is useless. This should never happen. Your code should never hit a situation where L is nullptr. It must assume that the instance on which it runs, has not been deleted.

Amazing answer! really thank u a ton! i'm actually always a worried kind of guy that's probably why i wanted to do that, but hey! if it wasn't for that i probably wouldn't have learned this pretty useful information! :D

As someone in the comments mentioned, the whole problem with the code is that i'm setting L to something once it was deleted, meaning its memory isn't in control anymore and can be changed at any time(also is this why they say C++ is memory unsafe?) so when i'm setting it to nullptr it's like throwing it into the river and there's no telling it'll still be nullptr once i check it later anymore!
I actually thought i solved it before reading the comments, by doing this:
#include <iostream>
struct node {
    int item;
    node *next = nullptr;
};
node *L;
class list {...}

But then they mentioned it's actually luck based once i change L to nullptr or whatever, since that memory isn't in control of the program anymore it's just luck when i get the result i want. Since the whole point of if (L == nullptr) was just to check if the object is deleted, and there's no way to delete L and wanting this if to work, the i guess just using the deleted boolean is gonna help, although they said it's not really my own problem when a user calls a function of an object which its memory's been freed.
So i wrote this as the final solution to it:
class list {
    private:
        struct node {
            int item;
            node *next = nullptr;
        };
        node *L;
        bool deleted;
        unsigned int size;
    public:
        list() {
            deleted = false;
            size = 0;
            L = new node;
            L->next = L;
        }
        ~list() {
            if (!deleted) {
                popAll();
                delete L;
                deleted = true;
            }
        }
        ...
        void printArray() {
            if (deleted) return;
            node *p = L->next;
            std::cout << '[';
            while (p != L) {
                std::cout << p->item;
                if (p->next != L) std::cout << ", ";
                p = p->next;
            }
            std::cout << ']';
        }

just putted if (deleted) return; at the beginning of any other function.

You still miss the point.

wait... which one? i mean... the whole point was to kind of make the user not to use the object when it's deleted, in addition to actually freeing all of the memories it had taken.

The point is: the user should not access memory that is no longer allocated. As it is no longer allocated, you cannot leave any trace there that is of any reliability. Forget about deleted. Forget even the accessibility of the methods on a deleted object... Nothing is reliable when it resides in memory that is deleted. I don't know how I can explain it better than in the comments I already made, but the point seems not to come across. Any assignment to an instance field in the destructor is useless. So deleted = true is useless. That true becomes unreliable the next moment.
